# Getting Syntax error in parametrize insert query in python postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

**I am trying to send data to  PostgreSQL, data is a tuple of strings i.e (time, price).**

The problem is when I send data using a simple query (**not parametrized**) it works fine!
Following is the simple query working perfectly.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO paxos (date,price) VALUES ('2020-04-09 14:39:58.145804', '$1,664.08');");
```

But as those values aren't fixed, so I want to store them in variable and use a parameterized query for sending data, but the parameterized query isn't working for me. Here is the parameterized query.

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO paxos (date, price) values (?, ?)",(time, price))
```

Here is the complete function I am trying to implement:

```
def insert_data(time, price):

con = psycopg2.connect(database="", user="", password="", host="", port="5432")
print("Database opened successfully")
cur = con.cursor()

data_tuple = (time, price)

cur.execute("insert into paxos (date, price) values (?, ?)",(time, price))

con.commit()
print("Record inserted successfully")
con.close()
insert_data("2020-04-09 14:39:58.145804", "$1,664.08")
```

Here is the error message:
[image: image link]

Comment: Why is the price column a `varchar`?  That is a really bad idea

Comment: Do you think It can be a cause of error? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is a python syntax error. I think you should use the format method of the string object (see codesnippet below). 
I can't test it right now, but according to some old code of mine, I always "built" a query string first and then passed the string object to the cursor. Try something like that:

```
artist = "Aphex Twin"
title = "Windowlicker"    
query = '''SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tracks
                    WHERE artist ILIKE \'{}\'AND
                    title ILIKE \'{}\')'''.format(artist, title)
cursor.execute(query)
```